# Write shell output to MS Word document

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, text, libreoffice

#### Problem:

I usually output text from my shell to file using `>`. I am trying to find an equivalent process that outputs a MS Word document (.doc or .docx).

I was thinking to use libreoffice and came up with this using the [convert-to](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-soffice/) command:

```
echo "texthere" > tt.txt;   soffice --convert-to doc tt.txt
```

That is, I am first creating a plain txt document and then convert it to doc in a second step.

#### Question: Is there a one-step solution?

E.g. along the lines of:

```
echo "texthere" | command_to_output_as_doc filename.doc
```

Thanks! (I'm using GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1) on Elementary OS)

Comment: if `soffice` can read from standard input with the `-` argument ,that might work.

Comment: Just creating your output file as .doc or .docx should work.  `echo "texthere" > tt.docx`

Comment: @Jesse_b Nice, that was a lot easier than I thought, thanks! Not saying I quite understand it -- I  always figured .docx was such as complicated format.

Comment: @patrick, jesse_b's solution does not change format.  It just names your text file as `something.docx`.

Comment: @user4556274 Yes i see what you mean that makes sense. For my purpose that is fine (I just need this to open in Word for my co-workers) but I see how it is fundamentally different from a real conversion.

Comment: If you are only sending unformatted plaintext to the file there is no need for it to be "converted" (as there is nothing to convert).  The file will be "converted" when you open it with microsoft word but no changes will actually be made to the file unless you add some formatted text to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you might be able to use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/). It reads from stdin and can output to a variety of formats

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you see any issues with the approach suggested by Jesse_b above? It seems to produce legible docx format for me.

Comment: if you need or want any kind of formatting (bold, italics, tables, headings, etc) in the word doc, plain-text without markup won't do the job.  It's easy to generate markdown from a shell script (it's just plain text with markup characters like `#` and `*` embedded, same as is used here on U&L - pandoc understands several 'dialects' of markdown and several other input formats too) and then process it with pandoc to produce a .docx file (or .pdf or open-office .odt, or epub, and several others).

Answer (score 1):

This is just to add to the answer by @rcjohnson after testing it. 
[Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) does indeed do a very good job of converting various input to docx format, including formatted text.

For instance, the following Python script (saved as pandoctest.py)

```
print "Here we have **bold** and _italics_ and `code`"
```

Can be run as follows:

```
python pandoctest.py | pandoc --from markdown_github --to docx -o testdoc.docx
```

(indicating that the printout is to be read as Markdown, then saved as docx to *testdoc.docx*; unless an input file is specified, Pandoc reads from stdin)

This produces a Word document with formatting as shown:

> Here we have **bold** and *italics* and `code`

Pandoc has a lot more options for pdfs, different Markdown flavors, etc.

Comment: Why use Python when you could use `echo`? `echo 'Here we have **bold** and _italics_ and `code`'`

Comment: Agreed, this was more of an example string to illustrate how you can use output e.g. of existing scripts in general and more complex strings